json formating with jq for json nested objects
how do I get jq to take json like this:
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1
  },
  "cluster":{
    "collections":{
      "collection1-stored":{
        "pullReplicas":"0",
        "configName":"collection1-stored-conf1",
        "replicationFactor":1,
        "router":{
          "name":"compositeId"
        },
        "nrtReplicas":1,
        "tlogReplicas":"0",
        "shards":{
          "shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node2":{
                "core":"collection1-stored_shard1_replica_n1",
                "node_name":"servername1:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "leader":"true",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername1:8983/solr"
              }
            },
            "health":"GREEN"
          }
        },
        "health":"GREEN",
        "znodeVersion":3,
        "creationTimeMillis":1727780823546
      },
      "collection2-multi":{
        "pullReplicas":"0",
        "configName":"collection2-multi-conf2",
        "replicationFactor":2,
        "router":{
          "name":"compositeId"
        },
        "nrtReplicas":2,
        "tlogReplicas":"0",
        "shards":{
          "shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node3":{
                "core":"collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n1",
                "node_name":"servername1:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "leader":"true",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername1:8983/solr"
              },
              "core_node4":{
                "core":"collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n2",
                "node_name":"servername2:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername2:8983/solr"
              }
            },
            "health":"GREEN"
          }
        },
        "health":"GREEN",
        "znodeVersion":5,
        "creationTimeMillis":1727780813821,
        "aliases":["collection2-multi-query","collection2-multi-upd"]
      },
      "collection4-multi-multi1":{
        "pullReplicas":"0",
        "configName":"collection4-multi-multi-conf4",
        "replicationFactor":2,
        "router":{
          "name":"compositeId"
        },
        "nrtReplicas":2,
        "tlogReplicas":"0",
        "shards":{
          "shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-ffffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node5":{
                "core":"collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n2",
                "node_name":"servername1:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername1:8983/solr"
              },
              "core_node8":{
                "core":"collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n6",
                "node_name":"servername2:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "leader":"true",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername2:8983/solr"
              }
            },
            "health":"GREEN"
          },
          "shard2":{
            "range":"0-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node3":{
                "core":"collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n1",
                "node_name":"servername1:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "leader":"true",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername1:8983/solr"
              },
              "core_node7":{
                "core":"collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n4",
                "node_name":"servername2:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername2:8983/solr"
              }
            },
            "health":"GREEN"
          }
        },
        "health":"GREEN",
        "znodeVersion":7,
        "creationTimeMillis":1727780770838,
        "aliases":["collection4-multi-multi"]
      },
      "collection3-multi":{
        "pullReplicas":"0",
        "configName":"collection3-multi-conf3",
        "replicationFactor":2,
        "router":{
          "name":"compositeId"
        },
        "nrtReplicas":2,
        "tlogReplicas":"0",
        "shards":{
          "shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node7":{
                "core":"collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n1",
                "node_name":"servername2:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername2:8983/solr"
              },
              "core_node5":{
                "core":"collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n2",
                "node_name":"servername1:8983_solr",
                "type":"NRT",
                "state":"active",
                "leader":"true",
                "force_set_state":"false",
                "base_url":"http://servername1:8983/solr"
              }
            },
            "health":"GREEN"
          }
        },
        "health":"GREEN",
        "znodeVersion":6,
        "creationTimeMillis":1727780768553,
        "aliases":["collection3-multi-index","collection3-multi-query"]
      }
    }
  }
}

and generate this output:
collection1-stored, collection1-stored-conf1, shard1:core_node2, collection1-stored_shard1_replica_n1, servername1:8983_solr
collection2-multi, collection2-multi-conf2, shard1:core_node3, collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n1, servername1:8983_solr
collection2-multi, collection2-multi-conf2, shard1:core_node4, collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n2, servername2:8983_solr
collection4-multi-multi1, collection4-multi-multi-conf4, shard1:core_node5, collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n2, servername1:8983_solr
collection4-multi-multi1, collection4-multi-multi-conf4, shard1:core_node8, collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n6, servername2:8983_solr
collection4-multi-multi1, collection4-multi-multi-conf4, shard2:core_node3, collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n1, servername1:8983_solr
collection4-multi-multi1, collection4-multi-multi-conf4, shard2:core_node7, collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n4, servername2:8983_solr
collection3-multi, collection3-multi-conf3, shard1:core_node7, collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n1, servername2:8983_solr
collection3-multi, collection3-multi-conf3, shard1:core_node5, collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n2, servername1:8983_solr

using jq formatter.
Summarizing, I need to obtain for each collection name and for each of its shards and for each of its replicas, a row containing the collection name, the configName value, the core name, the core value and the node_name value.
I only was able to reach the firs level filtering as:
jq ".cluster.collections"

Thanks

Assuming you want CSV output:
$ jq -r -f script file
"collection1-stored","collection1-stored-conf1","shard1:core_node2","collection1-stored_shard1_replica_n1","servername1:8983_solr"
"collection2-multi","collection2-multi-conf2","shard1:core_node3","collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n1","servername1:8983_solr"
"collection2-multi","collection2-multi-conf2","shard1:core_node4","collection2-multi_shard1_replica_n2","servername2:8983_solr"
"collection4-multi-multi1","collection4-multi-multi-conf4","shard1:core_node5","collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n2","servername1:8983_solr"
"collection4-multi-multi1","collection4-multi-multi-conf4","shard1:core_node8","collection4-multi-multi1_shard1_replica_n6","servername2:8983_solr"
"collection4-multi-multi1","collection4-multi-multi-conf4","shard2:core_node3","collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n1","servername1:8983_solr"
"collection4-multi-multi1","collection4-multi-multi-conf4","shard2:core_node7","collection4-multi-multi1_shard2_replica_n4","servername2:8983_solr"
"collection3-multi","collection3-multi-conf3","shard1:core_node7","collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n1","servername2:8983_solr"
"collection3-multi","collection3-multi-conf3","shard1:core_node5","collection3-multi_shard1_replica_n2","servername1:8983_solr"

... where script is
.cluster.collections | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.configName] as [$collection, $config] |
.value.shards        | to_entries[] | .key as $shard |
.value.replicas      | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.core, .value.node_name] as [$replica, $core, $node] |
[$collection, $config, $shard + ":" + $replica, $core, $node] | @csv

This is essentially a triple loop, where...

The outer loop is iterating over the .cluster.collections entries, setting $collection and $config to the collection's key and the .configName attribute of the collection, respectively.
The second loop is iterating over the collection's shard entries, setting $shard to the shard's key.
The inner loop then iterates over the shard's replicas, producing an array with the needed information, i.e., the collection name, the configuration name, the shard name concatenated with the replica name, and finally, the replica's core and node name.

The arrays produced by the inner loop are passed through @csv to be converted to CSV records.  If you want to instead use a comma and space as the delimiter for the outputted fields, replace @csv with join(", ").
See also:

Documentation for to_entries.


Wonderful! It'just what I need. Thank you very much!
